# vb.net upload file problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

When I try to post a file its coming back false ie there was no file attached. Can anyone see anything wrong with this? Or what might be causing it.

```
<form id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSubmitApplication" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</form>

Protected Sub cmdSubmitApplication_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmitApplication.Click

    If Me.fileUpload.PostedFile Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write("You must specify file to upload!")
    Else

        Try

            Dim strExt As String = Path.GetExtension(Me.fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)

            If strExt.ToLower() = ".doc" Then

                Dim savedFile As String
                savedFile = Path.GetFileName(Me.fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
                Me.fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("cvs\") & savedFile)
                Response.Write("File Uploaded Successfully")

            Else
                Response.Write("Only Image Files are Allowed")
            End If

        Catch exp As Exception
            Response.Write(exp.Message)
        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it keeps telling me "You must specify file to upload!"

Comment: Just to clarify, this is ASP.NET 2.0?

Comment: Did you specify the upload size cap on the web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it. There was a  tag in the master, so the form I added below was nested. I removed the form tag from the master. Would that cause problems elsewhere. Should I just remove the form tag above instead of the master.

ps I hate vb.net and everything about it.

Comment: Yes, just have the form tag in the master page.

Comment: ASP.net needs a form in every page to do the magic. Just keep the form in the master page, and remove the child one.

Comment: BTW, it is not a VB.net thing, it is ASP.net

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
If Me.fileUpload.HasFile Then        
    Response.Write("You must specify file to upload!") 
Else
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a full working example from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00323245.aspx

please have a look.

also try replacing "If Me.fileUpload.PostedFile Is Nothing Then" with "If fileUpload.PostedFile Is Nothing Then"

and check permissions on the destination folder

Comment: permissions are fine. Made your changes and that msdn tutorial doesnt work either. Also, very hard to trust it, when they have <INPUT type=file and <input type="button in the same code block. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *enctype="multipart/form-data"* from the form tag. I'm looking at my pages that I use the upload on and they don't have it.

I have the form tag in a master page, but it's just:

< form id="form1" runat="server" >
< form >

Comment: that didnt do it. Im nearly sure that is required. Either way, didnt do it. hmmmm

Comment: fixed it. There was a <form> tag in the master, so the form I added below was nested. I removed the form tag from the master. Would that cause problems elsewhere. Should I just remove the form tag above instead of the master.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal BugID As System.Guid, ByVal Files As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload, ByVal fileDescription As String)
        Dim guid As System.Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid()
        Dim filesSave As New BugTrackerData.Files.Files()
        Dim filename As String = Files.PostedFile.FileName
        'Grab the file name from its fully qualified path at client 
        Dim strFileName As String = guid.ToString() & System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)
        'Save uploaded file to server at C:\ServerFolder\
        Dim savepath As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/FileUploads/" & strFileName)
        Try
           If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileUpload1.FileName) Then
 Files.PostedFile.SaveAs(savepath)
            filesSave.SaveToDB(guid, BugID, strFileName, fileDescription)
End If
        Catch Exp As Exception
            Throw Exp
        End Try
    End Sub
```